# Need little assistance in pexpect module on the usage of sendlines

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm using pexpect to telnet to a switch and do certain operations.

I have written a simple code as below:

```
child1 = pexpect.spawn(cmd1, timeout = 15)
child1.logfile = sys.stdout
j = child1.expect(prompt_list, timeout = 115)
if j == 1:
    print 'Inside username block'
    child1.sendline('test')
    j = child1.expect(prompt_list, timeout = 15)
```

when i use sendline , i see on my logs that it is being displayed twice. Not sure of the reason. can we prevent this?

```
Inside username block
test
test
```

Comment: Are you able to run your code in a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
child1.logfile = sys.stdout
```

use

```
child1.logfile_read = sys.stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your settings I will propose this solution:

```
child1.setecho(False) # Turn off tty echo
```

I think what you are experiencing is this tty echo.

Make sure that you do this before sending anything since this will empty your outgoing buffer and you might lose some information.

Comment: This does not help . I could see that every input is repeated twice.